# Get property value on Startup of application in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, startup

I want to get value of one property from application.properties in my spring boot application. Please see below code.

```
@Component
public class ContactEntityComp implements InitializingBean, CommandLineRunner
{
    @Value("${amqp.routes.get}")
    public String routes_get;

    @PostConstruct
    public void getCountryList() {
            System.out.println( " routes_get in  PostConstruct- "+routes_get);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println( " routes_get in  afterPropertiesSet- "+routes_get);

    }

        @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println( " routes_get in  afterPropertiesSet- "+routes_get);

    }
}
```

I want to get value of property - **amqp.routes.get** from application.properties while spring boot application startup.
I have tried with 1) @postConstruct annotation, 2) InitializingBean Interface, 3) CommandLineRunner Interface but I am getting null value of property from application.properties.
Is there any other way for this?

Comment: Can you please add code of what you're trying to achieve, ie accessing the value from properties file.

Comment: Hi @MadhuBhat Please see updated description.

Comment: What I meant was, the code of where you're trying to access this value which you're getting as null.

Comment: Hi @MadhuBhat Please see edited description. I have tried this code in different classes like Service, SpringBootApplication main class.

Comment: Have you tried these two configuration on top of the class you're trying to access the value?

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

Comment: @FarrukhAhmed Yes. I have tried but still I receive null value of property.

Comment: Strange I have used same property in my application.properties file and it is returning the expected value.

Comment: @FarrukhAhmed I don't know the reason but it works with Environment class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it like this.

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SomeConfigClass {
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  public Whatever someBeanFunc() {
    String desiredProp = env.getProperty("amqp.routes.get");
  }
}
```

This is especially useful if you are trying to access a lot of properties in one class.

Comment: @DhavalGoti no prolem